# Access files in s3n://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How I can I access the file sitting in the following folder of S3 which is own by someone else

s3n://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input

Answer (score 5):

The files in s3n://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input are public, and made available as input by Amazon to the sample word count Hadoop program. The best way to fetch them is to

1. Start a new Amazon Elastic MapReduce Job Flow (it doesn't matter which one) from the Amazon Web Services console, and make sure that you keep the the job alive with the Keep Alive option
2. Once the EC2 machines have started, find the instances on EC2 from the Amazon Web Services console
3. ssh into one of the running EC2 instances, using the hadoop user, for example
   `ssh -i keypair.pem hadoop@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
4. Obtain the files you need, using `hadoop dfs -copyToLocal s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input/0002 .`
5. sftp the files to your local system

Comment: Only the instance with the `ElasticMapReduce-master` has ssh open.

Comment: To get the entire directory, just omit the filename: `hadoop dfs -copyToLocal s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input/ .`

Answer (score 4):

You can access wordSplitter.py here:

https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py

You can access the input files here:

```
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0012
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0011
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0010
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0009
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0008
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0007
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0006
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0005
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0004
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0003
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0002
https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input/0001
```

Comment: When you go to the input file links it downloads a file and all of them only contain this `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 3):

The owner of the folder (most likely a file in the folder) must have made it accessible to anonymous reader.
If that is the case, s3n://x/y... is translated to 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/x/y...
or 
http://x.s3.amazonaws.com/y...

x is the name of the bucket.
y... is the path wihtin the bucket.

If you want to make sure the file exists, e.g. if you suspect the name was misspelled, you can  in your browser to open
http://s3.amazonaws.com/x
and you'll see XML describing "files" that is S3 objects, available.
Try this:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce

I tried this, and seems that the path you want is not public.
AWS EBS documentation quotes s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input in one of the "getting started" examples. But s3 is different from s3n, so input might be available to EMR, but not to HTTP access.

Comment: This is a much more practical solution, and at least as of today, the link http://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce/ is working and showing the result of a 'list-bucket' request.

Answer (score 3):

In Amazon S3, there is no concept of folders, a bucket it just a flat collection of objects. But you can list all the files you are interested in a browser with the following URL:
[s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce?prefix=samples/wordcount/input/](http://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce?prefix=samples/wordcount/input/)

Then you can download them by specifying the whole name, e.g.
[s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input/0001](http://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input/0001)